# RegEx for matching a character in a string only if it isn't escaped

Tags: java, regex

How can I find and operate on a character in a string only if it isn't escaped (ie proceeded by an odd number of another character)?

Example:

Desired character: `|`

Escape character: `\`

`|` should be found (and operated on, for example split)

`\|` should *not*

`\\|` should

`\\\|` should *not*

Comment: I can write my own code to do this easily enough but I feel that would probably be re-inventing the wheel, and somebody's probably come up with a more efficient method than I would probably write.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a regex repetition mode for "an odd number of"?

Comment: Possibly.  `x(xx)*` will match an odd number of `x`.  Not sure if you can adapt this to what you need.

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense Dawood and is probably what I'll do if I do need to write my own function for this.  Still curious if Java has a built in function for this though.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yup the regex will be something like `\\(\\\\)(.)` but that will need to be escaped to `"\\\\(\\\\\\\\)(.)"`. Probably or something. I'm not really into regexs.

Comment: Of course, you can't have infinite repetition in a lookbehind, so it's going to be a multi-step process.

Comment: No hang on. `"[^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)*([^\\\\])"`, as you mustn't be surrounded with \, I missed the `*` and other things. Sometimes `toCharArray` is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative a lookbehind to define a boundary:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\|
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3uqKGd/1)

Taking care of backslashes in Java, above regex would be:

```
(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\\|
```

Comment: I see somebody has updated the question to make it regex specific when I initially asked how to do this in Java.  That's fine, but for those wondering, here's the above as Java code:
                String line = "my|line";
  String regex = "(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\|";
  String[] parts = line.split(regex);
If anybody knows of a builtin Java way of doing this, or if the above could me made more efficient, I'd love to know.